# LaTeX Rendering in EaselJS

Tags: javascript, html, latex, easeljs, mathjax

Is it possible to utilize MathJAX or a variant inside of an EaselJS DisplayObject?  I'm open to alternative solutions.

I would like to display some text like $$ 5 + 3 -3 = 5$$ on a canvas which is an EaselJS stage.

Ideally I would like to use the Text Class, i.e.:

```
new createjs.Text("\( 5 + 3 = 8 \)", "20px Arial", "#ff0000");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a bit this was a working solution that I found.  It is not perfect, but it can move around:

**HTML**

```
<div class="canvasHolder">
    <div id="latexContent">\(3 + 4 = 7\)</div>
    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="600" height="600">Not supported</canvas>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("gameCanvas");
var domElement = new createjs.DOMElement(document.getElementById("latexContent"));
stage.addChild(domElement);
```

[Here is a demonstration of the snippet working.](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyNovo/7mdMz/)